# How do I print a list using a print function I defined earlier in the script?

Tags: r

[homework question]

I'm creating an S3 constructor/object/script. I have a list in my script that needs to be printed like:

```
ID: 9876  Name: Virgil  Gender: M
LDL: 248* HDL: 45+  Triglycerides: 148
```

I defined a print function earlier.

```
print.ChlorReads <- function(theObject) {
  cat("ID: ", theObject$id, " Name: ", theObject$name, " Gender: ", theObject$gender,
      "\n", "LDL: ", theObject$ldl, " HDL: ", theObject$hdl, " Triglycerides: ", theObject$trigl)
}
```

How do I properly use that script so that it prints each item in the list in the format specified above?

I can get it to print the list via print(lst), but, the list looks like this:

```
[[1]]
$id
[1] 1111

$name
[1] "Charlene"

$gender
[1] "F"

$ldl
[1] 111

$hdl
[1] 81

$trigl
[1] 136

attr(,"class")
[1] "Patient"

[[2]]
$id
[1] 2222

$name
[1] "Charles"

$gender
[1] "M"

$ldl
[1] 141

$hdl
[1] 78

$trigl
[1] 123

attr(,"class")
[1] "Patient"

[[3]]
$id
[1] 3333

$name
[1] "Kate"

$gender
[1] "F"

$ldl
[1] 121

$hdl
[1] 63

$trigl
[1] 141

attr(,"class")
[1] "Patient"

[[4]]
$id
[1] 4444

$name
[1] "Alice"

$gender
[1] "F"

$ldl
[1] 97

$hdl
[1] 79

$trigl
[1] 111

attr(,"class")
[1] "Patient"

[[5]]
$id
[1] 5555

$name
[1] "Jason"

$gender
[1] "M"

$ldl
[1] 121

$hdl
[1] 85

$trigl
[1] 123

attr(,"class")
[1] "Patient"

[[6]]
$id
[1] 6666

$name
[1] "Spencer"

$gender
[1] "M"

$ldl
[1] 111

$hdl
[1] 81

$trigl
[1] 127

attr(,"class")
[1] "Patient"

[[7]]
$id
[1] 7777

$name
[1] "Mary"

$gender
[1] "F"

$ldl
[1] 108

$hdl
[1] 86

$trigl
[1] 120

attr(,"class")
[1] "Patient"

[[8]]
$id
[1] 8888

$name
[1] "Jarrod"

$gender
[1] "M"

$ldl
[1] 252

$hdl
[1] 38

$trigl
[1] 411

attr(,"class")
[1] "Patient"

[[9]]
$id
[1] 9999

$name
[1] "Cary"

$gender
[1] "M"

$ldl
[1] 121

$hdl
[1] 47

$trigl
[1] 139

attr(,"class")
[1] "Patient"

[[10]]
$id
[1] 1234

$name
[1] "Michael"

$gender
[1] "M"

$ldl
[1] 123

$hdl
[1] 49

$trigl
[1] 134

attr(,"class")
[1] "Patient"

[[11]]
$id
[1] 2345

$name
[1] "Charlotte"

$gender
[1] "F"

$ldl
[1] 135

$hdl
[1] 69

$trigl
[1] 361

attr(,"class")
[1] "Patient"

[[12]]
$id
[1] 3456

$name
[1] "Blake"

$gender
[1] "F"

$ldl
[1] 95

$hdl
[1] 57

$trigl
[1] 126

attr(,"class")
[1] "Patient"
```

Edit: Here's the output of dput(lst), as asked for in the comments:

```
list(structure(list(id = 1111L, name = "Charlene", gender = "F", 
    ldl = 111L, hdl = 81L, trigl = 136L), .Names = c("id", "name", 
"gender", "ldl", "hdl", "trigl"), class = "Patient"), structure(list(
    id = 2222L, name = "Charles", gender = "M", ldl = 141L, hdl = 78L, 
    trigl = 123L), .Names = c("id", "name", "gender", "ldl", 
"hdl", "trigl"), class = "Patient"), structure(list(id = 3333L, 
    name = "Kate", gender = "F", ldl = 121L, hdl = 63L, trigl = 141L), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "gender", "ldl", "hdl", "trigl"), class = "Patient"), 
    structure(list(id = 4444L, name = "Alice", gender = "F", 
        ldl = 97L, hdl = 79L, trigl = 111L), .Names = c("id", 
    "name", "gender", "ldl", "hdl", "trigl"), class = "Patient"), 
    structure(list(id = 5555L, name = "Jason", gender = "M", 
        ldl = 121L, hdl = 85L, trigl = 123L), .Names = c("id", 
    "name", "gender", "ldl", "hdl", "trigl"), class = "Patient"), 
    structure(list(id = 6666L, name = "Spencer", gender = "M", 
        ldl = 111L, hdl = 81L, trigl = 127L), .Names = c("id", 
    "name", "gender", "ldl", "hdl", "trigl"), class = "Patient"), 
    structure(list(id = 7777L, name = "Mary", gender = "F", ldl = 108L, 
        hdl = 86L, trigl = 120L), .Names = c("id", "name", "gender", 
    "ldl", "hdl", "trigl"), class = "Patient"), structure(list(
        id = 8888L, name = "Jarrod", gender = "M", ldl = 252L, 
        hdl = 38L, trigl = 411L), .Names = c("id", "name", "gender", 
    "ldl", "hdl", "trigl"), class = "Patient"), structure(list(
        id = 9999L, name = "Cary", gender = "M", ldl = 121L, 
        hdl = 47L, trigl = 139L), .Names = c("id", "name", "gender", 
    "ldl", "hdl", "trigl"), class = "Patient"), structure(list(
        id = 1234L, name = "Michael", gender = "M", ldl = 123L, 
        hdl = 49L, trigl = 134L), .Names = c("id", "name", "gender", 
    "ldl", "hdl", "trigl"), class = "Patient"), structure(list(
        id = 2345L, name = "Charlotte", gender = "F", ldl = 135L, 
        hdl = 69L, trigl = 361L), .Names = c("id", "name", "gender", 
    "ldl", "hdl", "trigl"), class = "Patient"), structure(list(
        id = 3456L, name = "Blake", gender = "F", ldl = 95L, 
        hdl = 57L, trigl = 126L), .Names = c("id", "name", "gender", 
    "ldl", "hdl", "trigl"), class = "Patient"))
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of `dput(lst)` to your post? It would make it much easier for others to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I think either doing `print.ChlorReads(lst)` will work, or do `class(lst) <- c('ChlorReads', class(lst))` (so that R knows that lst is a ChlorReads) and then `print(lst)` should also work. Though your output suggests that `lst` is a list of many patients, and `print.ChlorReads` looks like it is supposed to print an *individual* patient rather than a whole list of them?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee You're correct, and I just realized that too. After double-checking the assignment, I'm supposed to create a loop that prints all of the list items, while still using the original print function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the example of a `list` with `patient` entries, we should use two different print methods. One print method that deals with the `list` structure by dispatching each elements print command to another that deals with the class of `patient`.

To conform with `print.*()` S3 methods - a.k.a pass a CRAN check on package submit - you must have the name of the object as `x` and then `...`

```
# Prints the patient information (one item in the list)
print.Patient = function(x, ...){

  cat("ID: ", x$id, " Name: ", x$name, " Gender: ", x$gender,
      "\nLDL: ", x$ldl, " HDL: ", x$hdl, " Triglycerides: ", x$trigl,"\n", sep="")

}

# Print function defined for list type
print.ChlorReads = function(x, ...) {

  # Process each item in the list
  for(i in seq_along(x)){

     # Call the method to print patient info
     print.Patient(x[[i]]) 

  }
}
```

Now, the next bit you need to do is define the class of `lst` to be of `ChlorReads` by:

```
class(lst) = c('ChlorReads', class(lst))
```

The inclusion of the present class via `class(lst)` enables a fallback to a generic S3 supported type.

Thus, after sourcing the `print` statements and the above sample object given in the opening post, I get the desired results with:

```
class(lst) = c('ChlorReads', class(lst))

print(lst)
```

This gives:

```
ID: 1111 Name: Charlene Gender: F
LDL: 111 HDL: 81 Triglycerides: 136
ID: 2222 Name: Charles Gender: M
LDL: 141 HDL: 78 Triglycerides: 123
ID: 3333 Name: Kate Gender: F
LDL: 121 HDL: 63 Triglycerides: 141
ID: 4444 Name: Alice Gender: F
LDL: 97 HDL: 79 Triglycerides: 111
ID: 5555 Name: Jason Gender: M
LDL: 121 HDL: 85 Triglycerides: 123
ID: 6666 Name: Spencer Gender: M
LDL: 111 HDL: 81 Triglycerides: 127
ID: 7777 Name: Mary Gender: F
LDL: 108 HDL: 86 Triglycerides: 120
ID: 8888 Name: Jarrod Gender: M
LDL: 252 HDL: 38 Triglycerides: 411
ID: 9999 Name: Cary Gender: M
LDL: 121 HDL: 47 Triglycerides: 139
ID: 1234 Name: Michael Gender: M
LDL: 123 HDL: 49 Triglycerides: 134
ID: 2345 Name: Charlotte Gender: F
LDL: 135 HDL: 69 Triglycerides: 361
ID: 3456 Name: Blake Gender: F
LDL: 95 HDL: 57 Triglycerides: 126
```

Comment: This is really close to what I need, but now I'm getting the error message: Error: could not find function "print.Patient". I have the print.Patient function earlier in the file.

Comment: @Ashley my fault on that. I didn't define the `print.Patient()` function properly. Try running the above code again.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to loop over the length of the list that you are passing as a parameter.

Try this small modification:

```
print.ChlorReads <- function(theObject) {
for (i in 1:length(theObject)){
  cat("List entry: ", i, "\nID: ", theObject[[i]]$id, " Name: ", theObject[[i]]$name, " Gender: ", theObject[[i]]$gender,
      "\n", "LDL: ", theObject[[i]]$ldl, " HDL: ", theObject[[i]]$hdl, " Triglycerides: ", theObject[[i]]$trigl,"\n")
 }
}
```